# when use fetch function laravel api with nuxt3 error 500 internal server error?

Tags: request, nuxtjs3, laravel-api, usefetch

i tried all of things and saw a lot of problems, then i solved the problem of sanctum with (scrf-cookie) request and i got the cookie work...

with env laravel file i tried all of cases with it, then tried with full correct info for files of laravel then i do not know what is the problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjlAq.png)

my problem now: i get the login 500 response.. with tried everything... i solved 419 response but this is with no any problem i think in my code (laravel)files (nuxt)codes get this 500 internal server error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVxft.png)

can you help me guys!?

am trying to connect api with (nuxt3) client correct with no problem, but i get some of problems make an error for request of nuxt with useFetch function of nuxt

Comment: Please check, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors -> code, text, logs, error-msg should be shared as text (in code fences) and not as image